# The radiative modes of an asymptotically flat spacetime and the symmetries

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, hamiltonian-formalism, asymptotics

In Ashtekar's [paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.525169), the radiative degrees of freedom of an asymptotic flat spacetime in general relativity are obtained. These degrees of freedom live on the null infinity $\mathscr I$, given by the equivalence classes $\{D\}$ of the covariant derivatives $D$ which annihilate the (degenerate) metric $q_{ab}$ and the normal $n^a$ to $\mathscr I$. 
By equivalence, it means that if $(D_a-\tilde D_a)K_b=fq_{ab}n^cK_c$ for some function $f$ and an arbitrary covector $K_a$ on $\mathscr I$, $D_a$ is equivalent to $\tilde D_a$. 
There are multiple $D_a$'s for this pair $(q_{ab},n^a)$ because $q_{ab}$ is not invertible. 
The collection of $\{D\}$ is the space $\Gamma$.

There is a natural conformal transformation evolved in describing the geometry of $\mathscr I$:

$$
\bar q_{ab}=\omega^2q_{ab},\quad \bar n^a=\omega^{-1}n^a.
$$

This pair $(q'_{ab},n'^a)$ is as good as the original pair $(q_{ab},n^a)$ in describing $\mathscr I$. The above conformal transformation can be generated by a vector field $\xi^a$ with the following property,

$$
\mathscr L_\xi q_{ab}=2kq_{ab},\quad \mathscr L_\xi n^a=-kn^a,
$$
with $k$ some function on $\mathscr I$ and $\mathscr L_nk=0$.

In the paper, Ashtekar showed some theorems. The last one states that

> There is a natural isomorphism between $\Gamma_V$ and $S_p$, which is a set of Poincare subgroups of the BMS group.

Here, $\Gamma_V$ is the space of ``vacuum'' whose $\{\mathring D\}$ is trivial. $S_p$ is the set of some Poincare subgroups of the BMS group.

The author proved this theorem in several steps. In the first step, he showed that an infinitesimal BMS transformation, i.e., a vector field $\xi^a$ can be chosen such that $(\bar q_{ab},\bar n^a,\{\mathring{\bar D}\})$ can be related to $(q_{ab},n^a,\{\mathring D\})$ in the following way

$$
\bar q_{ab}=\omega^2q_{ab},\quad \bar n^a=\omega^{-1}n^a,\quad (\mathscr L_\xi \{\mathring D_a\}-\{\mathring D_a\}\mathscr L_\xi)K_b=K_{(a}\{\mathring D_{b)}\}k.
$$

Here, $\omega\propto\exp(\int k)$. The last expression is the infinitesimal version of $(\{\mathring{\bar D}\}_a-\{\mathring D\}_a)K_b$. This way, the covariant derivatives for $(q_{ab},n^a)$ are related by some suitable conformal transformations, forming a group $G\in S_p$. Once one chooses a $\{\mathring D\}$, one can find such a group $G$, which defines a map from $\Gamma_V$ to $S_p$.

The next step is to show that this map is one-to-one. So the author started with two covariant derivatives $\{\mathring D\}$ and $\{\mathring{\tilde D}\}$ for $(q_{ab},n^a)$, which are related via the following expression,

$$
(\{\mathring{\tilde D}\}_a-\{\mathring D\}_a)K_b\hat =n^cK_c\mathring D_a\mathring D_bf,
$$
for some function $f$ with $\mathscr L_nf=0$. Here, the symbol $\hat =$ means that the both sides share the same traceless part.

Following the similar idea in the first step, one can find a group $\tilde G$ for $\{\mathring{\tilde D}\}$. 
The infinitesimal version of $\tilde G$ is a Lie algebra whose elements are called $\tilde\xi^a$. 
These elements should satisfy the similar equations to that of $\xi^a$, i.e.,

$$
(\mathscr L_{\tilde\xi} \{\mathring{\tilde D}_a\}-\{\mathring{\tilde D}_a\}\mathscr L_{\tilde\xi})K_b=K_{(a}\{\mathring{\tilde D}_{b)}\}k.
$$
Ashtekar wrote that $\tilde\xi^a=\xi^a-fn^a$, and it satisfies the above relation, once $\xi^a$ satisfies the equation of its own.

So I checked, using $(\mathscr L_\xi \{\mathring D_a\}-\{\mathring D_a\}\mathscr L_\xi)K_b=K_{(a}\mathring D_{b)}k$, to find out that

$$
(\mathscr L_{\tilde\xi}\{\mathring{\tilde D}_a\}-\{\mathring{\tilde D}_a\}\mathscr L_{\tilde\xi})K_b=2K_{(a}\mathring{\tilde D}_{b)}k+n^cK_c[(1-k)\mathring D_a\mathring D_bf+\mathring D_a\mathring D_b(\xi^d\mathring D_df)-2\mathring D_{(a}f\mathring D_{b)}k].
$$

I never obtained the correct equation. 
I am not sure what the problems are, and I need your help!